# Spring Kafka consumer often stop consume message from topic sometimes

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

I am using spring kafka dependency to build a kafka consumer to consume message from the topic. It often stop consuming message suddenly and there is no any error in log. If I restart the service, it can consume message normally. But it may stop consuming message again at some moment.

It is not possible to consume message over the max polling interval because each message will be processed within 1 min and the default max polling interval is 5 mins. And the frequency of message published is very low, it is around 1-2 messages per min.

Anyone has encountered this problem? How can I solve it?

Comment: could you share please the logs before the consumer is stopping !

Comment: by default your poll retreive 500 records (if there data on topics of course) configured by the max.poll.records. If in your consumer log you see that it's leaving the group because it exceed the "max.poll.interval.ms" then you could decrease the max.poll.records or increase the max.poll.interval.ms.

max.poll.records X time spent to process one record < should be lower then max.poll.interval.ms

Answer (score -1):

Do I understand that correctly that your consumer may take up to a minute to process the message before committing? Is this a blocking operation?

I suspect the problem might be heartbeats not being sent. Your consumer has a thread that sends a heartbeat to the Kafka brokers. By default that happens every `heartbeat.interval: 3s`. If your consumer is to busy to send the heartbeat, the broker might think it is dead after `session.timeout.ms: 45s` (`30s` in older versions). Especially in Java I have seen so high loads in the consumer that this happened in practice.

If this is the case

1. you should see messages in the *broker* logs which tell you the consumer left the consumer group
2. you could try increase `session.timeout.ms`. The only drawback is, that it will take longer to detect actual failures.

Comment: There is no relation between processing message and heartbits.
The consumer has a separate thread to send heartbits.
But may be he have to increase the max.poll.intervall.ms